# How to convert string to list which is in json format

Tags: python-3.x

```
import json    
accept_suggested_timings = """{"2023-11-20 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-21 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-22 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-23 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-24 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-27 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-28 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-29 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-30 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 22:00:00"}]}"""
print(list(accept_suggested_timings))
a = json.loads(accept_suggested_timings)
b = list(a)
print(b)
```

Is there any solution to convert string to json.

Required solution: [
{"2023-11-20 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-21 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-22 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-23 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-24 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-27 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-28 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-29 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-30 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 22:00:00"}]}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this:

Code:

```py
import json

accept_suggested_timings = """{"2023-11-20 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-21 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-22 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-23 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-24 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-27 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-28 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-29 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-30 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 22:00:00"}]}"""

a = [json.loads(accept_suggested_timings) for i in accept_suggested_timings]

print(a) # your list
```

Check the [output here](https://www.online-python.com/DmIk4LEuGU)

Comment: Thanks is it possible to get first three dates from it 2023-11-20, 2023-11-21, 2023-11-22

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the dates, check this:

```py
import json

accept_suggested_timings = """{"2023-11-20 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-20 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-20 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-21 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-21 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-21 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-22 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-22 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-22 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-23 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-23 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-23 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-24 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-24 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-24 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-27 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-27 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-27 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-28 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-28 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-28 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-29 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-29 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-29 22:00:00"}],"2023-11-30 00:00:00":[{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 14:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 16:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 18:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00"},{"startDateTime":"2023-11-30 20:00:00","endDateTime":"2023-11-30 22:00:00"}]}"""

a = [json.loads(accept_suggested_timings) for i in accept_suggested_timings]

my_dates = []
count = 0
for i in a[0]:
    dates = i.split(" ")[0]

    my_dates.append(dates)
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        break

print(my_dates)
```

[output of the code](https://www.online-python.com/RHlEDsgJM7)